# Why does AskUbuntu keep telling me about the video tutorials?

Tags: discussion, design

It seems like every page has a header saying:

> Is this your first time here? Take a look at our Video Tutorials for using the site.

Does that text ever change? I have more than 200 rep, so I'm not a new user. The tutorials aren't new.

I think it bothers me so much because there's so much space in the header. There's a big blank space next to "Ask question". Maybe we could use that blank space to showcase new features (like videos) instead of adding the perma-bar underneath.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Moderators can set the message along that bar. The whole point of it is to get people's attention so they show up to all users, targetting isn't (yet possible). The messages expire after two days, unless the moderators manually re-deploy them.

The design is point is interesting though, I think it might look a bit odd though. On a netbook I can see the problem.

Comment: It's to all users, and for a maximum of 2 days. We've had a high influx of new users so we're ensuring they understand how to use the site

Comment: @Marco thanks, I've updated my answer

Comment: @marco I understand the influx of users with a new release, so that's fine.. but moderator messages are limited to 48 hours max to avoid potential long term ["boy who cried wolf"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Boy_Who_Cried_Wolf) issues.